# Localhost - Emulator - Cache Access Denied

Tags: android, caching, localhost, emulation

Here's my original question which is now irrelevant :

> I'm trying to parse an XML file using `SAXParser`. The code *worked*
>   for the past one week. However all of a sudden, I keep getting a
>   `SAXException`: `Wrong XML file structure: expected: /meta read: head
>   (position:END_ ... TAG </head>@109.8 in
>   java.io.StringReader@41221168)`
>
> I tried the same code for different xml files in my localhost. I can't
>   understand why this could happen all of a sudden when it has been
>   working for the past few days!

UPDATE :  I tried printing the xml string that was stored. Turns out that the required file is not being read at all. Some problem with the localhost. The string that is being stored instead says I require authentication to access the file. But I've not been giving any authentication till now.

Comment: Look up your XML file closely. Perhaps you are missing an end-tag or you have a not well-formed file

Comment: @Enigman, on this site, you generally ask one question at a time. You may be getting downvotes because you have obviously asked one question, then simply asked another one without mentioning a resolve to your original. You should either accept an answer to your original question (which will increase your reputation) or delete this post, and post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

From the error it looks like you must have a start tag `<meta>`, but end that section with `</head>` instead of `</meta>`.

Comment: (if that is not the case, please post your XML)

Comment: Hey, there's no problem with the XML file. Seems like the file is not being read at all! Instead it reads some error file of some sort asking me authentication to access the file. Never happened before I've updated my question.